# How inline object via jackson JsonGenerator?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

Consider example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Exmaple {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        Object object = new Object() {
            private String id = "someId";
        };

        final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(System.out);
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("data");
        generator.writeBinary(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\!Temp\\elasticsearch\\pdf.pdf")), -1);
        generator.writeEndObject();
        generator.writeObject(object);
        generator.close();
    }
}
```

The goal is to add all fields from `object` during json streaming. With that code I got:

```
{
  "data": "JVBERi0xLjMKJ="
} {
  "id": "someId",
}
```

How tell `jackson` to not write `{}` from object?

**UPDATED**

The exprected result is (e.g. `data` + all keys from java object):

```
{
  "data": "JVBERi0xLjMKJ=",
  "id": "someId",
}
```

Comment: You gave an example of data you don't want (two objects, which makes perfect sense that it is happening since you write code to generate two objects). So what data *do* you want? Give an example of that too.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: You could always use `ObjectMapper` insteed.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call `writeEndObject()` after you call `writeBinary` It should look like:

```
final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(System.out);
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("data");
        generator.writeBinary(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\!Temp\\elasticsearch\\pdf.pdf")), -1);
        generator.writeObject(object);
        generator.writeEndObject();
        generator.close();
```

Comment: It leads to insert object without field name. E.g. `{}` brase are inserted inside previuos object.

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonSerializer` type has an `unwrappingSerializer` method that "unwraps" the serializer. For the `BeanSerialier` (which is the serializer used for writing objects), the returned serializer will simply not write the start and end of the object.

The provided example, rewritten to use this, looks like this:

```java
final SerializerProvider serializerProvider = /* obtain serializer provider */;
final JsonSerializer<Object> objectSerializer = serializerProvider.findValueSerializer(object.getClass());
final JsonSerializer<Object> unwrappingSerializer = objectSerializer.unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP);

final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(System.out);
generator.writeStartObject();
generator.writeFieldName("data");
generator.writeBinary(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\!Temp\\elasticsearch\\pdf.pdf")), -1);
unwrappingSerializer.serialize(object, generator, serializerProvider);
generator.close();
```

Obtaining the `SerializerProvider` depends on the actual implementation, as the provided example does not use an `ObjectCodec`. Optimally, this code would live inside the `serialize` method of a custom serializer, where the `SerializerProvider` is given as an argument.

The `NameTransformer` passed to `unwrappingSerializer` can be used to easily map the names, for example by prefixing them. Using `NameTransformer.NOP` just writes the names as they are written by the original serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to merge `object` variable into the `generator`'s target object. If you can access `object` variable and you know its properties than you can simply use `generator`'s methods to write them, e.g.:

```
generator.writeStringField("id", object.id)
```

Some properties might be complex objects (aka POJO) where you'll have to use `writePOJOField(String fieldName, Object pojo)`; for `writePOJOField` to work you'll have to properly instantiate your `JsonFactory`, e.g. `new JsonFactory(new ObjectMapper())`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/73702885/4681265.

The other more generic approach is to generate the `object` JSON and then write it into `generator`'s output using:

```
// see http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.13/
generator.writeRaw(char[] text, int offset, int len)
```

by skipping the `object` JSON's opening and enclosing braces.